# Grub Problem occuring after i unistalled one out of 3 OS

Tags: grub2

I had 3 os on my system Ubuntu 18.04 , 16 and Windows 10, after i unistalled 16 from my system the grub which was generated is not working properly  currently i am  logging into the system from 16's grub i think as it shows 3 os options there while the grub which was generated was not able to open anny os left.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After removing an OS, you need to update grub. Boot into your Ubuntu 18.04, and run
`sudo update-grub`. That should fix the problem.

You can also do it from a live media (USB, dVD, ...).